# HTTPoison sock5 proxy

Tags: proxy, elixir, socks, httpoison

I’m using HTTPoison to send HTTP requests through a proxy, but when I change the proxy’s port, HTTPoison doesn’t seem to automatically adapt:

```
iex(1)> HTTPoison.get! "http://httpbin.org/ip", %{}, [proxy: {:socks5,'127.0.0.1', 9052}]

%HTTPoison.Response{
  body: "{\n  \"origin\": \"156.54.213.67, 156.54.213.67\"\n}\n",

iex(2)> HTTPoison.get! "http://httpbin.org/ip", %{}, [proxy: {:socks5,'127.0.0.1', 3}]   

%HTTPoison.Response{
  body: "{\n  \"origin\": \"156.54.213.67, 156.54.213.67\"\n}\n",
```

Is there a way to force HTTPoison to use the port that was sent as an argument ?

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers):

> The port numbers in the range from 0 to 1023 are the ***well-known***
>   ports or system ports.[2] They are used by system processes that
>   provide widely used types of network services. On Unix-like operating
>   systems, a process must execute with superuser privileges to be able
>   to bind a network socket to an IP address using one of the
>   ***well-known*** ports.

What happens if you try a second port of 44555?